# Amending/Deleting tasks

Tags: task, gnucobol

I recently reinstalled VSCode having deleted it some time ago. I created a task to compile GnuCOBOL. However when I look at tasks.json my GnuCOBOL entries are there but also entries for the Ada language.

I've no idea how they got in there and when I want to run a (GnuCOBOL) task (Terminal -> Build task) all the options are prefixed with Ada.
So I deleted the Ada references in tasks.json - and ran Ada.build task assuming that my GnuCOBOL compile would run. Instead a I got these messages in Terminal:

```
Executing task: gprbuild -cargs -gnatef 

gprbuild: The term 'gprbuild' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

 *  The terminal process "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe -Command gprbuild -cargs -gnatef" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

So I would like to go back to square one - delete my tasks.json and, hopefully, all those prefixed with Ada and create a new tasks.json containing just the GnuCOBOL stuff.

Is there a recommended way to do this? Thanks